# Creating subclasses

Tags: java, subclass

I had to create a class using Account that was defined to model a bank account. (the account has the properties account number, balance, annual interest rate, date created, and methods to deposit/withdraw funds.)

How would i create two subclasses for checking and saving accounts? A checking account has to have an overdraft limit, but the savings cant be over drawn.

Any help or advice would be awesome, thank you(:

```
public class Accountdrv {
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Account account = new Account(1122, 20000, 4.5);

    account.withdraw(2500);
    account.deposit(3000);
    System.out.println("Balance is " + account.getBalance());
    System.out.println("Monthly interest is " +
      account.getMonthlyInterest());
    System.out.println("This account was created at " +
      account.getDateCreated());
  }
}

class Account {
  private int id;
  private double balance;
  private double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;

  public Account() {
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public Account(int id, double balance, double annualInterestRate) {
    this.id = id;
    this.balance = balance;
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
    dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id =id;
  }

  public void setBalance(double balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
  }

  public void setAnnualInterestRate(double annualInterestRate) {
    this.annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;
  }

  public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return balance * (annualInterestRate / 1200);
  }

  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
  }

  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }
}
```

Comment: u can create method in the Accountdrv class for indivitual action

Answer (score 0):

Consider defining one or more interfaces.
For example:

```
public interface Account
{
    public double getAnnualInterestRate();
    public Date getDateCreated();
    public int getId();
    public double getMonthlyInterest();

    public void deposit(double amount);
    public void withdraw(double amount);
}

public interface CheckingAccount
extends Account
{
    public long getOverdraftLimit();
}
```

It might be reasonable to add setters, but I prefer to either set the vlues in the implementing class constructor or put the setters in the implementing class, but not in the interface.  A reasonable exception might be setOverDraftLimit() in the CheckingAccount interface.

You are making some common money mistakes:

- money is not a floating point value.  it is a fixed point value.  `double` is never correct for money.  Use `long` instead and store as fractions of a unit (for example 10000 = 1 dollar).
- Learn how do perform interest calculations.  Annual interest rate is never 12 * monthly interest rate.